# Symfony 4 running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have recently finished an API in Symfony 4 and I was wanting to deploy it on AWS's Elastic Beanstalk for production testing. However, aside from being able to access the default Symfony 4 greeting in index.php [Symfony default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaCQt.png)

I am unable to route to any other logic. For instance when trying to use /note/view which works on local environment [note/view on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk3t3.png)

I am met with an "Undefined index /note/view does not exist" on the EB environment. Almost like my routes.yaml isn't loaded.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `.htaccess` file in your `public` directory (at least on your EC2 instance -the one that EB creates-)

Your local might not need it (like nginx) however, EB PHP comes with apache out of the box. You need to make sure your code will work on apache as well.

Just to test this theory, access to your EC2 instance that's created by EB (see below if you don't know how);

- `cd /var/app/current/public`
- `~ nano .htaccess`
- Paste contents below to the file;

`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Please note that this is just basic rewrite for apache to test this theory. You could add a lot more to this file depending on your project's needs.

- Restart apache; `sudo service httpd restart`
- Test it!

Alternatively instead of `cd /var/app/current/public`, you could do `cd /var/www/html/public` as it is symlink to the `/var/app/current/public`

**How to Access EB generated EC2 Instance**

- Go to AWS console -> Elastic Beanstalk -> Your Application -> Your Environment
- Once in environment Dashboard click "Configuration" on the left
- Find the box "Security" and click "Modify".
- Under "Virtual Machine Permissions" select your "EC2 key pair" and save.
- Go to EC2 -> Instances and find your EC2 instance's Public DNS (IPv4) and use it to access with your EC2 key pair (the pem file)

It will take a little while before you can login.

*PS* Of course one of the main idea behind EBS is that you shouldn't need to SSH into your instance. However this is just to test the theory and sometimes with AWS you need to go with trail & error style. I don't know the setup of this application nor the whole setup with EBS and its work-flow. If this is going to solve your issue, you can simply include `.htaccess` to your project and you are good to go.